# Clarification About the Function alexandria:length=

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sequence, compiler-optimization

The [Alexandria Manual](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Conses)
includes a boolean function for testing the length of sequences:

> Function: length= &rest sequences
> Takes any number of sequences or integers in any order. Returns true iff the length of all the sequences and the integers are equal. Hint: there’s a compiler macro that expands into more efficient code if the first argument is a literal integer.

The first sentence talks about "integers" (plural). Is this simply for testing whether several computed integers are the same, at the same time as testing for sequence lengths? Or is there some deeper significance?

The third sentence offers an optimization. Does this mean that counting over a list will stop when the literal index is reached, making it potentially more efficient than (= (length lst) 3) if lst is lengthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first sentence talks about "integers" (plural). Is this simply for testing whether several computed integers are the same, at the same time as testing for sequence lengths? Or is there some deeper significance?

There is no deeper significance. It is probably just for symmetry. Basically, `(length= ...)` with only integer arguments is simply a slower `=`. But the primary use case for this is `(length= 3 (some-list))`, i.e., the test whether some sequence has a specific length ("has the sequence value produced by `(some-list)` a length of 3?").

> The third sentence offers an optimization. Does this mean that counting over a list will stop when the literal index is reached, making it potentially more efficient than `(= (length lst) 3)` if `lst` is lengthy?

Yes, this is actually the case; the compiler macro expands into a call to `sequence-of-length-p` which (for lists) does something akin to that (via `nthcdr`).